# jQuery DataTables Master/Details (child rows) as a laravel partial view

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application where I am using jQuery DataTables ([yajra/datatables laravel plugin](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)) to display some records. I am also using 3 child rows to display more detailed information for them. In the child rows I display some extra information, a graph with yearly data of the content, and the values of the record for the last 6 months. The problem is that I cannot fill the last 2 child rows with the data like I filled the first, because I cannot put all the data inside 1 query.

Here is the controller methods that feeds the DataTable

```
public function getRowDetails()
{
    return view('reports.creates', compact('data'));
}

public function getRowDetailsData()
{

    $kpi = $this->getUserActiveKpi();
    $data = DB::table('reports')
              ->orderBy('month','desc')
              ->groupBy('kpi_id')
              ->take(5)
              ->get();
    return Datatables::of($kpi, $data)
              ->make(true);
}

private function getUserActiveKpi(){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $kpis = DB::table('kpis')
              ->where('kpi_status',1)
              ->where('responsible_user', $user->id);
    return $kpis;
}
```

this is the initialization script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table;
    table = $('#monthly_table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        dom: "fr<'clear'>Ttip",
        ajax: '{{ url("reports/row-details-data") }}',
        tableTools: {.....},
        columns: [.....],
        order: [[1, 'asc']]
    });
});
```

here are the functions that return the child row data:

```
var kpi;
function kpi_info(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>KPI:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.kpi_code + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Workload:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.kpi_workload + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>KPI Description:</td>' +
    '<td>'+ d.kpi_description + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>'
}
function kpi_values(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    kpi = d.id;
    // it returns the id, here I want to return the partial view 
    // that contains the data using the *kpi* as a parameter
    return kpi; 
}
function kpi_graph(d) {
    kpi = d.id;
    // it returns the id, here I want to return the partial view that
    // contains the graph using the *kpi* as a parameter
    return kpi; 
}
```

and here is the function to show them:

```
$('#monthly_table tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);
        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(kpi_data(row.data())).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is that when I click one of the links that shows the childrow, feed the `kpi` parameter to the following controller method

```
public function data($id){
    $data = DB::table('reports')
              ->where('kpi_id',$id)
              ->orderBy('month','desc')
              ->take(5)
              ->get();
    return view('reports.data', compact('data'));
}
```

If there is anything else you should know please ask, and all the help is appreciated

**EDIT**

by saying `I cannot put all the data inside 1 query` I mean that I have to combine 3 queries to do that. First is:

```
DB::table('kpis')
    ->where('kpi_status',1)
    ->where('responsible_user', $user->id);
```

The second one is:

```
DB::table('reports')
    ->where('kpi_id',$id)
    ->orderBy('month','desc')
    ->take(5)
    ->get();
```

And the third one is:

```
DB::table('reports')
    ->where('reports.is_validated',1)
    ->where('reports.year',$current_year)
    ->orderBy('month','asc')
    ->get();
```

I can't think of a query that can get all these data at once.

**Note**

there is another query like the last one with the `$prev_year` parameter.

**EDIT 2**

```
Schema::create('kpis', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('kpi_code');
        $table->string('kpi_description');
    });

Schema::create('reports', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('kpi_id')->unsigned()->nullable(); 
        //fk kpi -> values
        $table->float('value');
        $table->integer('month',false,false,'2');
        $table->integer('year',false,false,'4');
    });

Schema::table('reports', function($table){
        $table->foreign('kpi_id')->references('id')->on('kpis');
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I cannot put all the data inside 1 query." and give some examples.

Comment: Is the data related? You could leverage Laravel's Eloquent.

Comment: yes i am using eloquent

Comment: When I use `DB::table(...)` I usually save that for extremely complex queries. If you setup your models the right way you could do something like.  `$kpis = Kpi::with('reports')->where('kpi_status',1)->where('responsible_user', $user->id)->get();` You'd have to show how your data relates in order to help you out.

Comment: @whoacowboy i included that query in the javascript. and i got the data. however i want to pass a parameter through the javascript function but that is not working. i'll post a new question and will comment the link here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343759/passing-parameter-in-eloquent-orm-inside-a-javascript-function here is the new question @whoacowboy

Comment: Can you post you db structure for `kpis` and `reports`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will need to be edited, but hopefully you get the idea.

I would look at [Eloquent: Relationships > Defining Relationships > One To Many](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) as well as the Datables demo site page, [EloquentController.php - eloquent.getHasMany.title.](http://datatables.yajrabox.com/eloquent/has-many)

**Kpi Model**

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Kpi extends Model {

  /**
   * Get the reports for the kpi.
   */
  public function reports()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report')
        ->orderBy('month','desc');
  }
  /**
   * Get the Kpis for a specific user
   */
  public function scopeForUser($query, $user_id)
  {
        $query->where('kpi_status',1)
      ->where('responsible_user', $user_id);
  }
}
```

**Report Model**

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Report extends Model {
    /**
     * A report belongs to a kpi
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function kpi()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Kpi');
    }
    /**
     * Get the reports for a specific year
     */
    public function scopeForYear($query, $year)
    {
        $query->where('is_validated',1)
            ->where('year',$year)
            ->orderBy('month','asc');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function getRowDetails()
{
    return view('reports.creates');
}

public function getRowDetailsData()
{
    if (Auth::guest())
    {
        return ['status'=>'error', 'nessage' => 'Unauthorized user.'];
    }
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $kpis = Kpi::with(['reports' => function($q){
        $q->take(5);
    })->forUser($user_id)->get();
  return Datatables::of($kpis)
           ->make(true);
}
```

The `->take(5)` might limit your query to a total of only 5 records and not 5 reports per KPI. If that is the case check out [this article](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

**Updated per comments**

It doesn't look like that plugin you are using offers nested loops

You might be able to do something like this, but I have never used that plugin, so I am unable to give you any more information.

```
columns: [
  {data: 'kpi_code', name: 'kpi'},
  {data: 'kpi_workload', name: 'workload'},
  {data: 'kpi_description', name: 'description'},
  {data: 'reports[0].name', name: 'report_1'},
  {data: 'reports[1].name', name: 'report_2'},
  {data: 'reports[2].name', name: 'report_3'},
  {data: 'reports[3].name', name: 'report_4'},
  {data: 'reports[4].name', name: 'report_5'}
]
```

Comment: `->take(5)` works fine. however i can't seem to iterate to all the 5 records in reports through javascript

Comment: @xhulio I updated my answer, I think you may be out of luck with that plugin. I think a new question with your specific issue to display might be in order.

Comment: i'm looping over them with javascript, it's just that it doesn't accept a any variables at `data.report[i].name` it says `cannot read property name of undefined`

Comment: try `data.reports[i].name` with an s.

Comment: it wasn't that the problem. actually i put a wrong counter at the for loop therefore it showed `undefined error` because the index doesn't exist.